# Ionic build - android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm new to app development. This is my first app.
I was going through the tutorials and trying to configure Ionic for building an app but I can't make it build.

Here is the error:
    ERROR: Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

```
Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1/bin/android

You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

and here is my Android SDK install:
[config top screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJDxu.png)
[config bottom screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELZmE.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the box at API 22 and hit install.